# Exception Handling in OCaml

Tags: exception, ocaml

Say we have these two functions:

```
let divide_and_match x y =
  match y with
  | 0 -> raise (Failure "Division by zero")
  | _ -> x / y

let divide_ten x y =
  match x with 
  | 10 -> 
    let result = divide_and_match x y in 
    print_endline ("Result: " ^ string_of_int result)
  | _ -> failwith "Bad"
```

I understand that if x was some input other than 10, "Bad" would get printed out, however I was curious about this:
Would any error from divide_and_match x y besides the Failure "Division by zero" also result in "Bad" printed out?? Would divide_ten ever catch any errors from divide_and_match x y?

I was just confused on how exception handling works in match with cases i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Your `divide_ten` function does not catch any exceptions, so we can provide `0` as a value for the argument `y` and we don't get `"Bad"`:

```
# divide_ten 10 0;;
Exception: Failure "Division by zero".
```

If you want to do that, you need to be explicit about it.

```
# let divide_ten x y =
    match x with
    | 10 ->
      (try 
         let result = divide_and_match x y in
         Format.printf "Result: %d\n" result 
       with 
       | Failure _ -> failwith "Bad")
    | _ -> failwith "Bad";;
val divide_ten : int -> int -> unit = <fun>
# divide_ten 10 0;;
Exception: Failure "Bad".
```

Note that `Invalid_argument` would probably be a more appropriate exception to throw in this situation.

Comment: Also, side question, is there ever a case where some exception not caught/raised in function A is caught by function B, following explicitly just the format above where both functions only have "match __ with ..." ? Or can function B only catch errors not caught by function A  when we have try ... with blocks?

Comment: An exception raised propagates back up the call stack until it is handled (or not). Handling an exception can include re-raising it. Probably after taking some other action.